# How can I access a List using the value of another List with EL?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have two Lists. The first list ( numberList) contains two integer elements: [1] and [5]
The second  list (stringList) contains ten String.
I'd like to use EL to display the first and the fifth element of the second list using the number 1 and 5 contained in the first one.
I'd like to write something like this using EL:

```
<c:out value="${stringList[numberList[0]]}" />
<c:out value="${stringList[numberList[1]]}" />
```

Is it possible using EL?

Comment: The code is fine, haven't you try it? If you want to get the first and fifth instead of [1] and [5], it is [0] and [4].

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly valid.

Assuming the following servlet

```
List<Integer> numberList = Arrays.asList(0, 4);
request.setAttribute("numberList", numberList);
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
request.setAttribute("stringList", stringList);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and the following JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:out value="${stringList[numberList[0]]}" />
<c:out value="${stringList[numberList[1]]}" />
```

you should see this in your webbrowser when invoking the servlet

> one five